# What type of spiral is it?

Tags: differential-geometry, polar-coordinates, parametric, curves

I want to write this spiral in cartesian coordinates and parametric or polar coordinates.

[image]

and how can I write the distance between two points of this spiral?

$$D= \sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2 + (y_2-y_1)^2}$$

I also want a spiral with big curvature to the beginning, then more small, so, $r_1<r_2<r_3<r_4<r_5\ldots $

Comment: Spirals are not made of semicircular pieces. Although you can convert this to polar coordinates (piecewise definition with $-\pi\le\theta<0$, $0\le\theta<\pi$, etc.), you can't do any better than what you already have. Curvature is going to be constant on intervals, undefined at integer multiples of $\pi$.

Comment: Why can not Spirals  be constructed in this way?, So, how are spirals made? Are there conditions?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spiral#Two-dimensional, you are welcome.